# How can I extract email headers and message IDs from arbitrary text?

Tags: regex, perl

The following test program illustrates a problem I'm having trying to differentiate MessageIDs from Email addresses, especially when I have no prior knowledge that I'm parsing an email header.

```
#!/opt/perl/bin/perl
  # use Regexp::Debugger;
  use warnings;
  no warnings qw(experimental::vlb);

  my $re = qr{
          (
              (?:
                  # one or more of these
                  [\=a-z0-9!\#$%&'*+/?^_`{|}~-]+
                  # zero or more of these
                  (?:\.[\=a-z0-9!\#$%&'*+/?^_`{|}~-]+)*
              )
              @
              (?:
                  (?!\d+\.\d+)
                  (?=.{4,255})
                  (?:
                      (?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,63}(?<!-)\.)+
                      [a-zA-Z0-9-]{2,63}
                  )
              )
          )
  }xims;
  my $text = <<'EOF';

  Arbitrary text followed by a snippet of an email header:

  To: "T B" <tbruner@foo.com>, "Foobar" <foo@bar.com>
  Message-ID: <adfadsfadsf@adsfasdf.com>

  More text.

  EOF

  while ( $text =~ m/$re/g ) {
      print "$1\n";
  }
```

Output:

```
tbruner@foo.com
foo@bar.com
adfadsfadsf@adsfasdf.com
```

My desired output is

```
tbruner@foo.com
foo@bar.com
```

I've tried adding a look behind `(?<=To:\ )` but then I get no matches.

The larger program applies a couple hundred regexes against input text.  Each regex is a specific type, e.g. foo => qr/[Ff]oo/ and if it matches, that text gets "wrapped" with a marker that identifies what regex it matches.  E.g. <span class="foo">foo</span>.

Comment: what you need to use is a lookbehind `(?<=(From|To))` before your expression so that there is a "constrain" that indicates when a match is possible but that is not part of your matched text.

Comment: Don't try to do it one step. First find to and from lines and then extract the addresses.

Comment: Do you have to do this in a single regexp? Wouldn't it be easier to first find all the headers you care about, then extract the email addresses from them?

Comment: *"...  if the line begins ..."* - The assumptions that is has to be the same line is wrong for mail. A header field can span multiple lines in a mail, i.e. things like `To: foo@example.com,\r\n<space> bar@example.com\r\n` are perfectly fine and might even needed to a limit of 1000 on the line length. Parsing mail headers is very tricky and easily to get wrong. Better do it in steps instead of trying it within a single regex.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Agree and I know about the multiple line.  The problem is I have no knowledge that I'm parsing Email headers.  Sometimes users paste excerpts of email headers into broader text and the request is to find email addresses as email addresses and message-ids as message-ids.  Best effort type situation.  Its unfortunate that the designers of email decided to wrap both in < > .

Comment: @zdim I've included a sample perl program that demonstrates the problem

Comment: If you are trying to deal with top-posted Outlook messages, your next hurdle is that it mindlessly translates the headers into "human readable" strings which sometimes even vary between versions. So you need `Von:` and `Avsändare:` and `Lähettäjä:` and etc etc etc to cover `From:`, and similarly for the other headers. Bottom line, don't let people use Outlook (there ought to be a law).

Comment: I revisited this and just realized that I'm not sure what you mean by "_especially when I have no prior knowledge that I'm parsing an email header_" -- that emails may be given in a format different from the example you show?  The examples show `"name" <abc@x.y>`  ... I thought I answered that, with or w/o the _"name"_ part -- but did you really mean to say that an address may be given in some other format as well?  Perhaps just as `abc@x.y`?  Or what does the absence of knowledge that it is email headers mean (or imply)?

Comment: no prior knowledge means that the program is parsing user supplied text which may or may not include snippets they copied and pasted from an email header. So above I want to reject the line with Message-Id. @zdim yes, the email may appear on other lines without a preceding "To:".

Comment: @Todd OK, thanks.  If there is no email in the text then an answer that matches and parses it (like mine) still works, it just won't match anything and so it won't find email, correctly.  But, if there is an email without `To:` (etc) then that's different -- that you'd just search using a general email format, as it has been done many times over.  There's even a regex library for that.  (It's also contained in my answer.)  So then you could first make a pass find emails with this `To:` & Co and have them removed (instead of merely matched), _then_ look for email alone. ... [cont'd below]

Comment: @Todd [cont'd]  "_email may appear on other lines without a preceding "To:"_"  -- while, on the other hand, if you mean to say that that "other" email (without `To:` etc) is of no interest then an answer which finds emails with `To:`, like mine, should be fine.  It won't catch a loose email (w/o `To:`)

Comment: zdim, I appreciate your comments and I realize I'm doing a poor job describing what is going on.  I've tried to simplify the problem to its essence, but may have overshot the mark.  This is a part of a larger application that looks at user input, finds matches from a set of 30+ regexes and wraps those matches in a <span> and applies a 'data-entity-type' attribute to that span based on the regex that matched.  E.g.  <span data-entity-type="email">foo@bar.com</span>, <span data-entity-type="ipaddr">10.10.10.1</span> or <span data-entity-type="msgid">adsfasdfs@adskasdf.com</span>.

Comment: [cont'd]... In light of that, my major problem is misidentifying msg-ids and emails. I was hoping to create a new regex that would be able to improve fidelity by looking behind and seeing "Message-ID" preceding it.  Since I control the order of the matches looking for that first would lower the erroneous matches.  (text once matched does not get additional regex applied towards it)

Answer (score 2):

With question clarifications (and a change to not request just a regex), here is one take on it.

First extract all headers, each with the text that follows, up to the next header (see further below for matching the header only).  Then we can fetch addresses from such captured items, from the headers we want.  Have to get *all* headers first, otherwise the unwanted ones would be slurped by the ones we match on.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

my $text = do { local $/; <DATA> };  # slurp all text into a scalar    
#say $text; say '-'x60;

# These better be all headers with email addresses in the text
my $hdr_re = qr/To|From|Message-ID/;
my @headers_plus = $text =~ /( $hdr_re: .*? )(?=(?:$hdr_re|$) )/sxg;

#say "\nHeaders with the following text (until next header):\n";
#say "$_\n---\n" for @headers_plus;

foreach my $hdr_plus (@headers_plus) {
    next if not $hdr_plus =~ /^\s*(To|From)/;
    my $header_type = $1;

    my @addresses = $hdr_plus =~ /<([^>]+)>/g;

    say "Addresses for |$header_type| header:";
    say for @addresses;
    say '';
}

__DATA__
Arbitrary text followed by a snippet of an email header:

To: "T B" <tbruner@foo.com>, "Foobar" <foo@bar.com>
Message-ID: <adfadsfadsf@adsfasdf.com>
From: "X Y" <test@haha.com>,
"Other" <header_can_spread@over.lines.com>

To: "Yo" <t@test.com>

More text.
```

I've added a few headers to the text from the question, one multiline. To match up to a next header's start I use [positive lookahead, `(?=...)`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut#Looking-ahead-and-looking-behind), for the next header's keyword (or end-of-string, if it's the last header in text).

This is fairly rudimentary, but the main point is that it is simple and it hopefully works for a simplified case shown in the question. But do keep in mind that parsing headers is tricky.

This approach being so simple, the regex is very permissive -- after each `To:` or `From:` or `Message-ID:` everything is captured until the next `To:` or `From:` or `Message-ID:`.  So it partitions most of the text and we may "catch" other email addresses if they exist in the text outside of headers. So perhaps you'd rather restrict what is captured after `To:` & Co.

For that let's loosely follow [from RFC 2822, secs 3.6 and 3.4](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2822) and consider that a `To` field can have comma-separated addresses and for an address take the form *`"name" <address>`* (and make name optional), as in the question. The list may have only one address, which then does *not* end in a comma, like for `From:` and `Message-ID`.  Then

```
my @headers = $text =~ / ( 
    $hdr_re: \s*
    (?: (?: "[^"]+")? \s* <[^>]+>, \s* )* 
        (?: "[^"]+")? \s* <[^>]+> 
) /xg;
```

This works in my tests with an extended question's sample.  But restricting the regex this way, which is still way incomplete, may of course lead to losing some real-life addresses and/or failing to match.  So test carefully on realistic samples.

---

Can also filter out unneeded headers right away

```
my @headers_plus = 
    grep { /^\s*To|From/ }
    $text =~ /( $hdr_re: .*? )(?=(?:$hdr_re|$))/sxg;
```

Then you could throw in a `map` and fetch addresses right there as well but I don't see a reason to cram it like that.

---

The regex in the text allows for headers to start anywhere in a line.  But if they always start at the beginning of a line then that's probably a good restriction to add.  Then we'd have

```
my @headers_plus = $text =~ /^\s*( $hdr_re: .*? )(?=(?:$hdr_re|\Z))/msxg;
```

Now we need the 'multiline' modifier (`/m`) so that `^` matches at new lines within the text.  Then the end of the whole string is `\Z` (since `$` now matches end of each "line" within text).

Same with the pattern matching the actual headers (without the following text, shown later in the post), except that there we don't need the `/s` modifier since `.` isn't needed in that pattern.

Comment: @Todd Added a regex for picking actual headers out of the text, more restricted than the "header-plus" that the original regex picks up (with everything that comes after the field name, until the next field name).  This is of course better -- but _if_ it matches all real-life headers in your texts, which now becomes a valid question.  (The original "header-plus" should of course match since it really just partitions the text.)  If they are as simple and consistent as you show this should work.

Answer (score 0):

The *Message-ID* field should only contain a single address.

*[RFC 2822 – Internet Message Format – 3.6.4. Identification fields](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2822#section-3.6.4)*

> *... The "Message-ID:" field contains a single unique message identifier. ...*

Try the following *capture pattern*.

```
(?<!^Message-ID:\s)<(.+?)>
```

Or, *match pattern*.

```
(?<!^Message-ID:\s<)(?<=<).+?(?=>)
```

Comment: this looks promising, I will test.  thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would write a script that *just* pulls out into a separate file anything that matches

```
/^\w+:/
```

i.e.: anything that looks like a header. Then I'd try to find a mail message parsing module and use that.